# Where to find worklight.plist?

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio, mobilefirst-cli

I'm using this URL to implement the App authenticity for iOS.
https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/application-authenticity-protection/application-authenticity-protection-native-ios/

However, I need to know where to find the worklight.plist to make sure that the applicationId is matching what i'm putting in the application-descriptor.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The worklight.plist file is available only after building the MobileFirst application using the MobileFirst Studio Eclipse plug-in (or CLI commandline tool).

- For Hybrid applications,
  You can then find the worklight.plist file in the `your-project\apps\your-app\iphone\native` folder.
- For Native applications,
  You need to only generate the NativeAPI for iOS and it'll be located in the generated folder, in `your-project\apps\your-nativeapi\WorklightAPI` folder. You then need to follow the native apps tutorial to copy over this (and more) files to the Xcode project.

Comment: Thank You, appreciate your response

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,
I have found it after building the project inside the native folder.